# Creating Electron JS health check endpoint or handling http request inside electron application

Tags: electron, health-monitoring, electron-packager, health-check

I want to check the health of the electron application.
Is there any possible way to handling http server side request inside electron JS application other than using node module like express?

i don’t want to use node modules like express inside front end components. So is there any inbuilt functionality that help to monitor the health state of electron application